# convert Strings to WebElements Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Im trying to convert my 7 Strings(xpaths) into WebElements and send keys for these labels, but only the first one is converted and my test sending keys only for the first one.

```
private static final String DAY_LABEL_VARIABLE = "//*[@id='app']/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td['%s']/div/div[2]/input";

    public TimeBuilder pickData() {
        String format = "";
        for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++) {
            format = String.format(DAY_LABEL_VARIABLE, i);
        }
        WebElement webElement = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(format));
        deletingAndAddingContentToLabel(webElement, sendNumbers0And23());

        return new TimeBuilder();
    }
```

I tried to add Strings into the list and go through with using for loop but the final outcome is the same like in code block before.

```
    public List<String> testList() {
        String format = "";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++) {
            format = String.format(DAY_LABEL_VARIABLE, i);
            list.add(format);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public TimeBuilder testElements() {
        for (int i = 0; i < testList().size() - 1; i++) {
            WebElement webElement = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(testList().get(i)));
            deletingAndAddingContentToLabel(webElement, sendNumbers0And23());
        }

        return new TimeBuilder();
    }
```

Of course there is an other solution by manually adding every locators and sending keys for them but its not a solution im looking for:

```
    public TimeBuilder sendHoursForEveryDayOfTheWeek() {
        mondayLabel.sendKeys(sendNumbers0And23());
        tuesdayLabel.sendKeys(sendNumbers0And23());
        wednesdayLabel.sendKeys(sendNumbers0And23());
        thursdayLabel.sendKeys(sendNumbers0And23());
        fridayLabel.sendKeys(sendNumbers0And23());
        saturdayLabel.sendKeys(sendNumbers0And23());
        sundayLabel.sendKeys(sendNumbers0And23());
        return new TimeBuilder();
    }
```

Thanks for help =)

Comment: you're building one string var there... each iteration overrites it.  The second one looks right, but where do you call testList()?   Might be easier to just put it all in the loop and add the iterator... "beginning of the xpath..." + i  + "the rest of the xpath"

Comment: might need i.toString()...